# How does the Yearling badge now work over multi years?

Tags: discussion, badges

I've been on SE site X for two years and six months, call it thirty months, and haven't gotten a Yearling badge. No surprise, since my reputation is less than 200.

In month 31, I "get active" on the site and my reputation starts to climb. I get a first, and then a second Yearling badge within days of each other. Specifically, I get these badges on the days that my rep rises past 200, then 400.

So did I meet a "dual" requirement? That is, I got badges for the lesser of the following two numbers: 1) the (completed) years on the site and 2) the whole number representing the quotient of the increase in my reputation divided by 200?

And if my rep on site X is now over 600, does that mean I'll get my third Yearling badge on my third anniversary on the site?

(There have been several other questions on the Yearling badge, but the protocols regarding it appear to have changed over time, so I haven't seen an "up to date" answer.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you miss the badge for a previous year, you won't get awarded that year's badge until you "catch up" to where you are supposed to be. So if you sit at, say, 50 reputation and then come back in 4 years, you will have to get up to 800 reputation and you'll receive *all four* badges at the same time.

Keep in mind that the equation used is simply *y * 200 + 1*, where *y* represents the numbers of years **as a decimal** you've been on the site. So if it's exactly your two-year anniversary and you have 401 reputation, you get the badge. If you pass your two-year anniversary and only have, say, 391 reputation, you don't get it for hitting 401 half-way through the year, because half-way through the year the requirement would be *2.5 * 200 + 1* which would come out to 501 reputation.

**Here's a simple way to think about it:** run your current site age through the formula *y * 200 + 1* (again don't round to the past year). If your reputation is greater than or equal, then the system will check your Yearling badges and make sure you have one badge for every full year you've participated on the site. If not, no new badges will be awarded.